# These things are what makes

Tags: construction

Answering the question, the student used the following:

> 'When the water vapor goes high, the cooler air causes water drops to stick to particles of dust or ice. **These things are what makes** clouds visible.'

Is it grammatically correct? And does it sound OK for a native speaker?

Comment: By "goes high" do you mean "rises" or "is more concentrated"? **This is why clouds appear** or **This is how clouds are formed.**

Comment: You could argue that the phrase **These things are what** regarded as a process or package could take the singular **makes**. Regarded as discrete actions, they would take the plural **make**. I think that a native speaker might well use either construction without attracting attention.